# Planning not doing

Tags: single-word-requests

What is a word for spending too much time planning, but never doing. 
It's not quite the same as procrastination.

Comment: _Overplanning_: noun:
the act or instance of planning excessively. [[Collins](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/overplanning)]

Answer (score 4):

"[*Analysis Paralysis*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_paralysis) is the state of over-analyzing (or over-thinking) a situation so that a decision or action is never taken, in effect paralyzing the outcome. ... The phrase describes a situation in which the opportunity cost of decision analysis exceeds the benefits that could be gained by enacting some decision". [Wikipedia]